# JQuery dynamic function based ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a function that posts AJAX requests.

I need to  call it from multiple pages, how can I make a callback method inside the done method? Or even a second callback for beforesend events.

```
function post_ajax(URL,CONTENT_TYPE,$RENDERING_DIV,PARAMS={},callback_function){
   $.post(URL, PARAMS, null, CONTENT_TYPE)
      .done(data => {
          callback_function()
      }).fail(() => alert('an error occurred'));
}

//function call
$('#mybtn').click(()=>{
    post_ajax('a_script.php','html','#div_res',{},callback_function())
})
```

Comment: You do `return $.ajax` then let your calling function handle the promise.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, as presented, you'd be better off using global ajax event handlers: https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: A global ajax event handler will not be dynamic. I need to make a dynamic function based ajax post request that i can be able to manipulate what ever is inside the done promise within the function call

Comment: @freedomn-m please write an answer to explain better and why the provided answers are not usable.

Comment: The key here, which you should have included in your question, is that you want to *manipulate the `data` within `.done` before passing it to the callback function*.  Providing the use-case / reason helps provide a sensible answer otherwise it looks like an XY Problem (re-inventing an existing wheel)

Comment: I didn't say the provided answers weren't usable, I said the question made no sense.

Comment: Okay but it's not about done method explicitly. It's how to call a function within the function call in general. The provided answers covered me.

Comment: Yes, I (eventually) realised that - again, would have been clearer to put that in the question up front and save everybody some time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of callback:

```
function post_ajax(URL, CONTENT_TYPE, $RENDERING_DIV, PARAMS={}, callback_function) {
    $.post(URL, PARAMS, null, CONTENT_TYPE)
    .done(data => {
        if (typeof callback_function === 'function') {
            callback_function(data);
        }
    })
    .fail(() => alert('an error occurred'));
}
```

And now you can call it:

```
$('#mybtn').click(() => {
    post_ajax('a_script.php', 'html', '#div_res',{}, (data) => { 
        console.log(data);
        alert('You are here'); 
    });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

your declaration is correct (expet sending result data to callback), the problem is in the call manner of the callback function

you need to pass a function declaration (not execution) or, just implement that function directly , by example :

first you have to pass the result as parameter to your callback in the done

```
.done(data => {
        callback_function(data) // <---- here pass data
    }).fail(() => alert('an error occurred')
```

then in the function event call :

```
//function call
$('#mybtn').click(()=>{
    post_ajax('a_script.php','html','#div_res',{},(data) => {
        console.log(data);
        //some stuff here manipulating data 
    });
})
```

Comment: what if i want to make a callback that accepts no parameters? Can you show an example?

Comment: In javascript if your function doesn't have parameters, then calling it with parameters will have those parameters ignored

Comment: Better to pass along as-is:  `$.post(..).done(callback_function)` then it will always get the correct parameters that `done` gets - but better still not to use a callback_function and use the promise.

Comment: yes ass @freedomn-m mentiened , to pass without parameter (mean catch every param sent) just se .done(callback_function);